# Loading a tensorflow.keras trained model using load_model returns JSON decode error, while untrained model loads normally

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have a trained Keras model built and trained using the tensorflow.keras API and saved using the `tf.keras.save_model()` method with no optional arguments. Tensorflow is up to date and my Python version is 3.8. From my understanding, this method should save the model using the default "tf" format, which is recommended in TF 2.X, and then using `load_model()` should work fine.

Loading the model again, however, produces the following:

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("/Volumes/thesis_drive/thesis_project_local_new/trained_model_640x64/")

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/c1/8tq0t8y90195qxyt5hppjjtr0000gq/T/ipykernel_933/1131710361.py in <module>
----> 1 model = tf.keras.models.load_model("/Volumes/thesis_drive/thesis_project_local_new/trained_model_640x64/")

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile, options)
    204         filepath = path_to_string(filepath)
    205         if isinstance(filepath, str):
--> 206           return saved_model_load.load(filepath, compile, options)
    207 
    208   raise IOError(

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py in load(path, compile, options)
    153 
    154   # Finalize the loaded layers and remove the extra tracked dependencies.
--> 155   keras_loader.finalize_objects()
    156   keras_loader.del_tracking()
    157 

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py in finalize_objects(self)
    624 
    625     # Initialize graph networks, now that layer dependencies have been resolved.
--> 626     self._reconstruct_all_models()
    627 
    628   def _unblock_model_reconstruction(self, layer_id, layer):

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py in _reconstruct_all_models(self)
    643       all_initialized_models.add(model_id)
    644       model, layers = self.model_layer_dependencies[model_id]
--> 645       self._reconstruct_model(model_id, model, layers)
    646       _finalize_config_layers([model])
    647 

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py in _reconstruct_model(self, model_id, model, layers)
    659   def _reconstruct_model(self, model_id, model, layers):
    660     """Reconstructs the network structure."""
--> 661     config = json_utils.decode(
    662         self._proto.nodes[model_id].user_object.metadata)['config']
    663 

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/json_utils.py in decode(json_string)
     60 
     61 def decode(json_string):
---> 62   return json.loads(json_string, object_hook=_decode_helper)
     63 
     64 

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py in loads(s, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    357     if parse_constant is not None:
    358         kw['parse_constant'] = parse_constant
--> 359     return cls(**kw).decode(s)

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    335 
    336         """
--> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

To test whether this is an error with `save_model()` or `load_model()`, I built the same model again in a Jupyter notebook, saved it, and reloaded it with no error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten, Dropout, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Input
from tensorflow.keras.losses import CategoricalCrossentropy
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

def build_model():
    _input = Input(shape=(640,64,3))
    x = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=4, input_shape=(640, 64, 3))(_input)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(4, 4))(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=4, input_shape=(640, 64, 3))(_input)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(4, 4))(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=4, input_shape=(640, 64, 3))(_input)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = Flatten()(x)
    output = Dense(161, activation = 'softmax')(x)
    model = Model(_input,output)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(), loss="categorical_crossentropy")
    tf.keras.models.save_model(model,"model_test")

model = build_model()

Metal device set to: Apple M1
2021-09-23 13:40:46.234438: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/pluggable_device/pluggable_device_factory.cc:305] Could not identify NUMA node of platform GPU ID 0, defaulting to 0. Your kernel may not have been built with NUMA support.
2021-09-23 13:40:46.234631: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/pluggable_device/pluggable_device_factory.cc:271] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 0 MB memory) -> physical PluggableDevice (device: 0, name: METAL, pci bus id: <undefined>)
2021-09-23 13:40:47.112730: W tensorflow/python/util/util.cc:348] Sets are not currently considered sequences, but this may change in the future, so consider avoiding using them.
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: model_test/assets

del model
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("model_test")
```

Further details: the model was trained on another machine (a supercomputer I have access to through my university) running Linux, and transferred to my Apple M1 machine via SCP, where it is now exhibiting this loading error.

I don't know why the JSON module is being called - there doesn't appear to be a JSON file anywhere in the directory. However, given that rebuilding the model without training and loading it produced no error, I am suspicious that the save did not execute correctly.

Comment: I had the same error - but from a different cause: I was able to save and load from my own machine - but had a problem when I copied my saved .pb as generated from a google colab Juypetyr notebook. So I'm guessing we're both experiencing some sort of version/build incompatibility??

Comment: Hi! @Sean Goldie! Could you please attach the code in Colab gist with mentioned error stack trace? Please check this issue again after saving the model file with arguments. It is throwing errors in some cases when the model is saved without arguments.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue with tensorflow 2.3.1.
Updated to 2.7 and now its working again!

Answer (score 0):

It is the incompatibility of TensorFlow versions between trained your model and the TensorFlow version you are loading the model. My server had TensorFlow versions 2.6.2 and my PC has 2.4.1. after training the model on the server, when I tried to load on my PC "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" error comes.

- check the TensorFlow versions on both the server and your PC. make sure they are similar.
- after I upgrade the Tensorflow on my PC, it successfully loads the trained model